# WSO2 3.1.0 APIM instance. Is it possible to configure the WSO2_CARBON_DB datasource to oracle configuration through the deployment.toml file?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

The master-datasources.xml is always overridden at startup with the default h2 database for the WSO2_CARBON_DB and WSO2MBStoreDB datasource.

**deployment.toml**

```
[server]
hostname = "localhost"
node_ip = "127.0.0.1"
#offset=0
mode = "single" #single or ha
base_path = "${carbon.protocol}://${carbon.host}:${carbon.management.port}"
#discard_empty_caches = false
server_role = "default"

[database.user]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"

[database.user.pool_options]
maxActive = 50
maxWait = 60000
testOnBorrow = true
validationInterval = 30000
defaultAutoCommit = true

[super_admin]
username = "admin"
password = "admin"
create_admin_account = true

[user_store]
#type = "database"
type = "database_unique_id"

[[datasource]]
id = "WSO2_CARBON_DB"
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
pool_options.maxActive = 100
pool_options.maxWait = 10000
pool_options.validationInterval = 10000

[[datasource]]
id = "WSO2_MB_STORE_DB"
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
pool_options.maxActive = 100
pool_options.maxWait = 10000
pool_options.validationInterval = 10000

[database.store_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
pool_options.maxActive = 100
pool_options.maxWait = 10000
pool_options.validationInterval = 10000

[database.identity_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
maxActive = "80"
maxWait = "60000"
minIdle = "5"
testOnBorrow = true
validationQuery="SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
validationInterval="30000"
defaultAutoCommit=false
[database.apim_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
pool_options.maxActive = 100
pool_options.maxWait = 10000
pool_options.validationInterval = 10000


[database.shared_db]
type = "oracle"
url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe"
username = "apimuser"
password = "wso2"
driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
validationQuery = "SELECT 1 FROM DUAL"
pool_options.maxActive = 100
pool_options.maxWait = 10000
pool_options.validationInterval = 10000



[realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"

[realm_manager.properties]
MultiTenantRealmConfigBuilder = "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.multitenancy.SimpleRealmConfigBuilder"

[user_store.properties]
TenantManager = "org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.JDBCTenantManager"
data_source = "WSO2USER_DB"
ReadGroupsPasswordHashMethod = "SHA"
Disabled = false
MaxUserNameListLength = 100
MaxRoleNameListLength = 100
UserRolesCacheEnabled = true
PasswordDigest = "SHA-256"
ReadGroups = true
ReadOnly = false
IsEmailUserName = false
DomainCalculation = "default"
StoreSaltedPassword = true
WriteGroups = true
UserNameUniqueAcrossTenants = false
```

The above changes not reflected in the data sources an WSO2_CARBON_DB and WSO2_MB_STORE_DB.

**master-datasources.xml**

```
<datasources-configuration xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">

    <providers>
        <provider>org.wso2.carbon.ndatasource.rdbms.RDBMSDataSourceReader</provider>
    </providers>

    <datasources>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for registry and user manager</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2CarbonDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;MVCC=TRUE</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_SHARED_DB</name>
            <description>Shared Database for user and registry data</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/SHARED_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</url>
                    <username>apimuser</username>
                    <password>wso2</password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <maxWait>10000</maxWait>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <validationInterval>10000</validationInterval>
                    <maxActive>100</maxActive>
                 </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>

        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2USER_DB</name>
            <description>User related database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2USER_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</url>
                    <username>apimuser</username>
                    <password>wso2</password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                 </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>


        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            <description>this database is WSO2_CARBON_DB</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2_CARBON_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                     <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</url>
                     <username>apimuser</username>
                     <password>wso2</password>
                     <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                     <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                     <validationInterval>10000</validationInterval>
                     <maxWait>10000</maxWait>
                     <maxActive>100</maxActive>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>
            <description>this database is WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                     <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</url>
                     <username>apimuser</username>
                     <password>wso2</password>
                     <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                     <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                     <validationInterval>10000</validationInterval>
                     <maxWait>10000</maxWait>
                     <maxActive>100</maxActive>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2AM_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for API Manager database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>jdbc/WSO2AM_DB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521/xe</url>
                    <username>apimuser</username>
                    <password>wso2</password>
                    <driverClassName>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</driverClassName>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1 FROM DUAL</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>10000</validationInterval>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>true</defaultAutoCommit>
                    <maxActive>100</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>10000</maxWait>
            </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>


        <datasource>
            <name>WSO2_MB_STORE_DB</name>
            <description>The datasource used for message broker database</description>
            <jndiConfig>
                <name>WSO2MBStoreDB</name>
            </jndiConfig>
            <definition type="RDBMS">
                <configuration>
                    <url>jdbc:h2:./repository/database/WSO2MB_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=60000;MVCC=TRUE</url>
                    <username>wso2carbon</username>
                    <password>wso2carbon</password>
                    <driverClassName>org.h2.Driver</driverClassName>
                    <maxActive>50</maxActive>
                    <maxWait>60000</maxWait>
                    <testOnBorrow>true</testOnBorrow>
                    <validationQuery>SELECT 1</validationQuery>
                    <validationInterval>30000</validationInterval>
                    <defaultAutoCommit>false</defaultAutoCommit>
                </configuration>
            </definition>
        </datasource>
    </datasources>

</datasources-configuration>
```

After startup server the data sources has been overridden as default.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please check out how to use SO. You should add some code fragments and maybe some images to show how far you already came with your example.

Comment: You do not need to configure all the databases and only need to configure APIM_DB and Shared_DB.

Answer (score 0):

In API-M 3.0 deployment, basically we only need to configure APIM-DB and Shared_DB.

WSO2_CARBON_DB is only used for internal usages of the node. Therefore, we do not encourage users to modify this configuration and it is best to keep as it is to avoid any unexpected errors. Due to this reason, it has not been added to the configuration model.

Comment: Thanking you, what about production for both data source. because as per document avoid h2 database for production.

Comment: This is for APIM_DB and Shared_DB which are used heavily and most often shared among multiple nodes. So it is not recommended to use H2 for these dbs.